# How to generate two primes p1, p2 bigger than 10^25

Tags: java, random, primes

I need to generate two primes p1, p2 bigger than 10^25, and their product n.
and a number "a" less than n.

Why I use the code below, the result of 4 number are all 0.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        long min = (long) Math.pow(10, 25);
        long max = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        long p1 = (long)((Math.random()+1)*(max-min));
        long p2 = (long)((Math.random()+1)*(max-min));
        long n = p1 * p2 ;
        long a = (long)((Math.random())* n) ;
        System.out.println("p1= " + p1 + ", p2= " + p2 + ", n= " + n +",a= " + a);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: 25 digits won't fit into a long, not to speak about the product. Use `BigInteger` and watch out for the methods dealing with prime numbers.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Large_primes ... things are **much** more complicated. And yes: first learn some basics, like "how do I work with numbers that don't fit the `long` range in Java".

Comment: `prime` is not the same as `random`

Comment: Can you describe your use case? Why do you need two large primes? What is `a` going to be used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obtain 0 because to represent `Long.MAX_VALUE` you need *63* bits, but to represent `10^25` you need *84* bits.

```
BigInteger maxLong = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE));        
BigInteger pow_10_25 = BigInteger.TEN.pow(25);
System.out.println(maxLong.bitLength()); // 63
System.out.println(pow_10_25.bitLength()); // 84
```

A possible solution is to use BigInteger:

- Determine the minimum of bit length to use
- Generate two probable prime number
- Multiply the two generated prime number

> By using [BigInteger.probablePrime(int, Random)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime(int,%20java.util.Random)): *"The probability that a BigInteger returned by this method is composite does not exceed 2-100."*

**Example**:

```
Random r = new Random();
BigInteger pow_10_25 = BigInteger.TEN.pow(25);
int minBitLength = pow_10_25.bitLength();

BigInteger p1 = BigInteger.probablePrime(minBitLength, r);
BigInteger p2 = BigInteger.probablePrime(minBitLength, r);  
BigInteger n = p1.multiply(p2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the following problem: the maximum value that a **long** can hold is **9223372036854775807** and your computation `Math.pow(10, 25)` exceeds that limit.
Thus, both your **min** and **max** will have the value **9223372036854775807** and the **max-min** becomes zero. And the problem continues on. Try using a type than can be larger, like **BigInteger**.

Answer (score 1):

This [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319570/where-can-one-find-a-list-of-prime-numbers) cites several locations to get lists of prime numbers:

- https://www.bigprimes.net/ (free?, not sure on license)
- http://www.primos.mat.br/indexen.html (free?)
- http://www.prime-numbers.org/premium.html (modest cost)

Instead of randomly generating these numbers acquire a listing of the prime numbers that satisfy the conditions for your problem. Load that file as an array or list in your Java application. Then randomly generate a number to select an index in that list. You could also count lines in the file and read a line from the file.

This approach trades CPU time (and maybe bugs?) for I/O and memory to read the list.

You should also consider setting an upper bound which is smaller than the largest value your numeric type can store. The largest prime is [over twenty million digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851936/how-far-is-the-list-of-known-primes-known-to-be-complete). `BigInteger` should be able to store that, however you may start running into memory limits with numbers that large.

Comment: I have the sneaking suspicion I am going to get schooled or downvoted. I am confident this strategy will work but I also suspect I am missing some obvious problem.

Comment: I don't think any of those links has primes of the right size. Plus I'm guessing this is for some cryptographic experiment so the primes should be generated randomly. But who knows, the OP hasn't give much info.